# version of share point 2010 which supports web services

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Out of the four microsoft sharepoint 2010 trial versions..viz. Enterprise Client Access license Features, Standard Client Access license Features, internet Sites Enterprise , internet Sites Standard, which one supports web service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is very unclear but let me give you two possible answers depending on your context; using the standard SP web services or hosting your own web services.

**Standard SharePoint Web Services**

All editions of SharePoint have web services which can be used to interact with it, as an alternative to using the SP Object Model in .NET. Each edition of course has some unique web services as the feature set is not the same.

You can read about SP 2013 web services at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193051(v=office.15).aspx and SP 2010 web services at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee705814.aspx. Please note that there are some changes to the support between 2010 and 2013, see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607742(v=office.15).aspx.

**Hosting Custom Web Services in SharePoint**

You can also host your own web services in SharePoint if you like. It is a perfect host for any WCF services you need to expose as part of your application. They should be deployed to _vti_bin, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff521581.aspx for reference!